# How to add a list of items to an ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml

I try to make a lucky wheel, I created a list of items for this wheel

```
List<SpinItem> spinItemList = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
spinList();
```

```
public class SpinItem {
        public String text;
        public int color;
        public int icon;
    }
```

```
private void spinList() {

        SpinItem item1 = new SpinItem();
        item1.text = "0";
        item1.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
        spinItemList.add(item1);

        SpinItem item2 = new SpinItem();
        item2.text = "5";
        item2.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
        spinItemList.add(item2);

        SpinItem item3 = new SpinItem();
        item3.text = "50";
        item3.color = 0xffFFCC80;
        spinItemList.add(item3);

        SpinItem item4 = new SpinItem();
        item4.text = "25";
        item4.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
        spinItemList.add(item4);

        SpinItem item5 = new SpinItem();
        item5.text = "15";
        item5.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
        spinItemList.add(item5);

        SpinItem item6 = new SpinItem();
        item6.text = "0";
        item6.color = 0xffFFCC80;
        spinItemList.add(item6);

        SpinItem item7 = new SpinItem();
        item7.text = "10";
        item7.color = 0xffFFF3E0;
        spinItemList.add(item7);

        SpinItem item8 = new SpinItem();
        item8.text = "100";
        item8.color = 0xffFFE0B2;
        spinItemList.add(item8);     
        
    }
```

**But now how do I add the list to my ImageView or do I have to change widget?**

PS: *I tried to add my custom view my application crashes on startup, that's why I'm trying to find an alternative*

Comment: what's the error u get when the app crashes ?

Comment: I don't know there is nothing written in the logs, my app just won't open ...

Comment: thats not possible, if the app crashes, there's gonna be something in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an array of objects, instead of creating 8 different object of same class?

```
SpinItem[] item = new SpinItem[8];
```

Then you can easily access through index.

What is the issue you are facing? Do you got any error while running the app?